# GoogleClientSecrets.cs not found youtube api v3

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I'm trying to upload files on youtube using youtube api v3. I have done everything well but I have one problem. When I'm debugging it vs says that it can't found GoogleClientSecrets.cs and then NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.cs not found. What's wrong? I have already updated `Install-Package Google.Apis.YouTube.v3` using nuget console.

And I have using

```
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;
```

I'm doing that using [this code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video)

Answer (score 0):

You've left out a couple of modules that are present in the code you linked to; specifically:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
```

is needed for GoogleClientSecrets.cs